# Refreshing contents of a jtable

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, jpanel

I have a `JTable` in a `JPanel` (called `cur_panel`) of a `JTabbedPane` which is fetching contents from a MySQL database. Now I want to be able to refresh the table whenever I make changes using the options in other pane of `JTabbedPane`. I got around this problem by destroying `cur_panel` and then again constructing it so that it could fetch refreshed data from the database.

Can someone suggest me a better way getting around it? Like if I could fetch only the new/modified data and withouut having destroy and then reconstruct the `JPanel`.

Answer (score 2):

You're right - you shouldn't need to re-construct the `JPanel`. Indeed, you shouldn't even need to reconstruct the `JTable`, or possibly even the `TableModel`. (Also, you might want to do some reading about the Model-View-Controller design pattern)

Instead, you should be resetting the data in the `TableModel`. I think this should cause the `JTable` to be repainted. If not, you could call:

```
table.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(tableModel));
```

Alternatively, if you feel it's better to construct a new `TableModel` with the new data:

```
table.setModel(newTableModel);
```

Here's an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of a `JTable` that is updated by something else... I've replaced the database connection with input from a `JTextField`, but it should give you the idea:

```
public class TableTest {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JTextField text = new JTextField("Editable Text");

    final TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Text"},1);
    model.setValueAt(text.getText(), 0, 0);
    text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        model.setValueAt(text.getText(), 0, 0);
      }
    });
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```